# Task.WaitAll AggregateException handling

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I've got a program processing results in batches of 100.  It makes api request (one item each) and then batch processes the results.

Recently, the api I'm calling has developed scaling problems and, say 10% of the requests fail/timeout at any given time.

My problem is that I'm trying to process the ones that *succeeded* and I'm getting new AggregateExceptions - but only one in the InnerExceptions.  It seems like I'm touching some kind of timebomb member in the Task array and I can't figure out what it is.

The outer loop sets up for the batch call and has the last-chance error handling:

```
try
{
    GetBatchStats();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    var firstE = e.InnerExceptions[0];
    _logger.Fatal($"{e.InnerExceptions.Count.ToString()} api requests threw exceptions.  Sample exception: {firstE.Message}\nStackTrace: {firstE.StackTrace}");
}
```

My original loop processing the batch had:

```
int asyncExceptions = 0;
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(batchRequests);
}
catch(AggregateException e)
{
    asyncExceptions = e.InnerExceptions.Count;
    var firstE = e.InnerExceptions[0];
    _logger.Error($"{asyncExceptions.ToString()} api requests out of {batchRequests.Length.ToString()} threw exceptions.  Sample exception: {firstE.Message}\nStackTrace: {firstE.StackTrace}");
}

if (asyncExceptions == batchRequests.Length)
{   // All requests in this batch errored out; api must be down
    throw new Exception("All api requests in batch returned errors.  Must be a problem with the api.");
}

int countErrs = 0;
foreach (var apiResult in batchRequests)
{
    if (apiResult.Exception != null || apiResult.Result == null) countErrs++;

    if (apiResult.Exception == null && apiResult.Result != null)
    { ...
    }
}
```

I would get the error message in the log about "X api requests out of Y threw exceptions", followed immediately by a fatal message about "1 api requests threw exceptions" indicating that

1. I was in the second loop trying to process the successes and
2. I touched something on a task in the array that caused a new AggregateException to be thrown - but I couldn't figure out what.

I tried replacing the Task.Exception references with other ways of phrasing it, but I got the same result:

```
int asyncExceptions = 0;
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(batchRequests);
}
catch(AggregateException e)
{
    asyncExceptions = e.InnerExceptions.Count;
    var firstE = e.InnerExceptions[0];
    _logger.Error($"{asyncExceptions.ToString()} api requests out of {batchRequests.Length.ToString()} threw exceptions.  Sample exception: {firstE.Message}\nStackTrace: {firstE.StackTrace}");
}

if (asyncExceptions == batchRequests.Length)
{   // All requests in this batch errored out; api must be down
    throw new Exception("All api requests in batch returned errors.  Must be a problem with the api.");
}

int countErrs = 0;
foreach (var apiResult in batchRequests)
{
    if (apiResult.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted || apiResult.Result == null) countErrs++;

    if (apiResult.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && apiResult.Result != null)
    { ...
    }
}
```

Hopefully another set of eyes might spot what I'm missing...  How do you process just the tasks in a group that had successful results and skip the ones that errored out?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use `await task.WhenAll` and then check the result on each task?

Comment: What is the inner exception that is caught in the outer loop? Any exception that is thrown from Task.Result will be wrapped in an AggregateException but the inner exception might have more information.

E.g., if a task has a status of `Canceled` then `apiResult.Result` will throw an `AggregateException`

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to respond.  Charlie - what would the different behavior be using WhenAll instead of WaitAll?  Tenatus - the exception is that some of the api requests time out.  I'm using the HttpClient async methods, so this this manifests as canceled exceptions.  But I'm puzzled why the first version checks of task.Exception *before* any reference to task.Result didn't protect against that?

Comment: Your outer catch prints some details such as `InnerExceptions[0].StackTrace`.  What was that stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of googling, it appears the answer is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

When a task in a group is canceled (e.g. HttpClient having a timeout),

1. AggregateException *does* have an exception in the collection for that
2. Task.Exception *is not* set
3. Task.Status has a separate code (not Faulted) for that.

Comment: Since it has a separate code (not `Faulted` but also not `RanToCompletion`) the second attempt in your question shouldn't have tried accessing `Status` and shouldn't have failed

Comment: @BenVoigt, that's a `||` in the first test so the check for `Result == null` is executed

Comment: @Tenatus: Oh of course.  I was focused on the wrong `if`.